# Nginx Basic Auth and subfolders

Tags: security, php, authentication, nginx

I have a problem with subfolders in a basic auth procted folder. In the protected folder i have a folder named phpmyadmin, which contains phpmyadmin. Im not able to run phpmyadmin, when basic is activated. Whenn i call the the folder, i get a save-as dialog (type: application/octet-stream (18,3 KB)).

Here the important parts of mysites-available/default

```
location ^~ /administration/ {
    auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/myproject/sec/htpasswd;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Any ideas, how i can run php in basic-auth protected subfolders?

EDIT: Without basic_auth phpmyadmin is running without problems.

Comment: Do you use phpmyadmin from here previously? Or it is an installation issue?

Comment: Without basic_auth phpmyadmin is running without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to do it like this: (pseudocode, sorry)

```
location /administration/ {
    <auth_stuff here>
    location ~ \.php {
        <php inside auth here>
    }
}
```

That's because auth only affects the location it is in.

I guess you could try removing `^~` (which tells nginx to stop searching, so the php location never matches for that directory) and see if it still requires auth despite not being explicitely required in the PHP block. It probably won't...

Unrelated but please also read http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Passing_Uncontrolled_Requests_to_PHP